# Create OpenSUSE bootable USB stick from Ubuntu?

Tags: usb-creator

OpenSUSE documentation (https://en.opensuse.org/SDB:Live_USB_stick) explicitly states that `unetbootin` wont work. They recommend using ImageWriter, but I haven't found a version for Ubuntu.

How can I create a bootable USB stick for OpenSUSE from Ubuntu?

Comment: same link says to use the command line  - did you follow those instructions?

Comment: @fossfreedom Note that I'm not trying to create a live USB stick. I just want to boot from the USB stick to install openSUSE. I read those instructions but it wasn't clear to me if they applied to the installation image as well as the live image.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> @fossfreedom Note that I'm not trying to create a live USB stick. I
>   just want to boot from the USB stick to install openSUSE. I read those
>   instructions but it wasn't clear to me if they applied to the
>   installation image as well as the live image. – becko 10 mins ago

Yes, those instructions do apply to installation USB creation. You will need to know the block device path of your USB stick.  Use `lsblk` to find that out. In this example I am using `/dev/sdb` but it could be anything else.

Ensure the usb stick is unmounted with

```
udisksctl unmount --block-device /dev/sdb
```

and burn the iso image to the USB

```
dd if=/path/to/downloaded.iso of=/dev/sdX bs=4M
```

For instance,

```
dd if=/home/xieerqi/Desktop/openSUSE-Leap-42.1-DVD-x86_64.iso of=/dev/sdb bs=4M
```

The command will take a long time to complete, so, be patient. You can use this

```
dd if=/home/xieerqi/Desktop/openSUSE-Leap-42.1-DVD-x86_64.iso of=/dev/sdb bs=4M  && zenity --info --text="DONE"
```

to show a notification when the burning is over.

Comment: This seems to work. Now how can I recover the drive for normal use?  The instructions on openSUSE website explain how to do it on Windows only.

Comment: You mean normal use as in make a storage device again ? There's nothing really to be done, just delete the files there. Or you can use `gparted` tool to format the disk again. It's not installed by default though.

Comment: Just want to mention that it is important to use `/dev/sdX` instead of `/dev/sdX1` in `dd`. The latter refers to a partition, but you need to write to full disk.

Answer (score 1):

Imagewriter exists on Ubuntu: https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/usb-imagewriter/

Otherwise, you can do it without additionals packages in command line:

```
sudo dd if=openSUSE.iso of=/dev/sd*
```

Where * is the letter of your USB stick (example: sda, sdb, ...)

Comment: that imagewriter seems to support only ubuntu 12

Comment: Wrong! Imagewriter is supports on all versions : https://launchpad.net/usb-imagewriter/+packages

Comment: Is there a way to install it through apt-get? I could not find it in the repos for 15.10.

Comment: Actually, following the link: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/wily/+source/usb-imagewriter, brings a message saying there is no release of this package for Ubuntu wily.

Comment: You write becko... I'm wrong

Answer (score 1):

Install pv to view the progress of the operation:
`sudo apt-get install pv`
then:
`sudo dd if=/path_to_the_opensuse_iso | pv | dd of=/dev/sd*`
where * is the letter assigned to your usb.